# $filter to find single item with ID (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to find an item in an array with an ID.
I get that ID from my url and I tried to use $filter to extract it from my array.

Here's what my code looks like :

```
$filter('filter')($rootScope.items,{ID_ITEM:$location.$$path.replace('/','')})
```

so bassically:

```
$filter('filter')($rootScope.items,{ID_ITEM:id})
```

It works but the problem is that it also returns other item with the same number in the ID

Example: If my url is #/3, it will return the object with id 23,13,3,33 etc...

How can I filter my array to only find the exact one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the `true` option to match exactly as the third parameter to the filter:

```
$filter('filter')($rootScope.items,{ID_ITEM:$location.$$path.replace('/','')},true)
```